# Pix2pix GAN applied to electrophoretic signal not generating realistic instrument noise

Tags: simulation, noise, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement the pix2pix network to be able to generate realistic electropherogram data. It is easy to simulate very clean, idealised data but it doesn’t have all the noise that makes the signal look realistic. The specific application I am interested in is DNA profile data, which detects 6 wavelength signals concurrently for 5000 time datapoints. I am having trouble getting the pix2pix implementation to generate realistic instrument noise.

Within DNA profile electrophoretic signal there are patterns that occur across the 5000 datapoints (within a wavelength), and patterns that occur across the wavelengths at the same timepoint. For this reason, I have been playing around with a variation of the U-net that has a horizontal component and a vertical component (structure shown below).

[image]

I am able to take real electrophoresis signal from DNA profiles and apply a smoothing algorithm that turns them into an idealised form. This means I have plenty of paired images; smooth and idealised vs the real profiles they came from.

My issue is that the generator cannot seem to generate the noise associated with real signal. The image below shows an example of the input profile at the top (smooth and idealised), the real profile it is targeting at the bottom, and the profile produced by the generator network in the middle.

[image]

You can see that the generated network has learnt to follow the shape of the real profile, but not the noise in the signal.  The discriminator network can always easy pick the difference between the real and generator profiles (as seen by the discriminator output in the image above) and basically isn’t really learning anything.

Although the pix2pix authors found that random noise input wasn’t required I thought that perhaps my implementation would benefit. I implemented a randomness component by taking the smoothed profile and just adding some random signal drawn from a normal distribution, which approximated the level of instrument noise in a real profile. The picture below shows the result, which is just that after about 1 pass through the dataset the generator had already learnt to ignore the randomness in the input signal and gave the same generated profile (I guess this reinforces the finding that the randomness doesn’t assist in the pix2pix network).

[input with noise (top), generated (middle) and real (bottom) signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp2zF.png)

My question is… why does the generator not learn to produce a noisy signal? And what can I do to get it to do so?  In relation to the images that pix2pix is normally applied to DNA profile data is pretty simplistic (just 6 strings of 5000 numbers) and so I thought it would be an easy task. Is the structure of my generator network limiting things?